Visiting Chile with Indian passport and less than 6 months on H1B Visa
I'm planning to visit Santiago next week for a trek and here's my info:

⁠Indian passport holder
⁠Have an US Visa (H1B) with 5.5 months validity

Given this info,

⁠Does anyone have experience traveling with slightly less than 6 months of validity on their US Visa?
⁠Does anyone know how strict the checks are while boarding from the US? Do they count the exact 6 month dates? Or are they merely looking for the presence of a US visa?

Lastly, are there any other avenues available for me to travel safely next week despite my unfortunate visa situation?

I wouldn't call 2 weeks+ "slightly less". A day or two, yes, not weeks.


Citizens of India holding a valid US Visa, with current validity of six months, do not require a Chilean tourist visa (either Simple Tourism or Multiple Tourism or Multiple-Business)

Assuming you don't have a separate visa for Chile and were hoping to use this exemption for the trip.
Based on the information in your post, it looks like you don't meet this criteria. You could try to call the airlines and ask for clarification.
Depending on how much time you have for the trip, you could try to get a Chilean tourist visa from the Chilean embassy in the USA.
Consider delaying your trip by a couple of weeks in order to get a tourist visa.

As long as your passport and US visa have at least 6 months of validity left on them, you can travel to Chile without any issues. I don't think they strictly check the US visa validity but the passport validity is usually strictly checked.

The OP stated they have less than 6 months.
